# why the deployement of .jar on JBOSS gives me :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, ejb

I have tow maven projects:

**1) named** `test` **where i have my tow interfaces**:

```
package interfaces.locals;
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Local
public interface IClientLocal {
void showClientName();
}

package interfaces.Remotes;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface IClientRemote {
void showClientName();
}
```

The `pom.xml`looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**2) named** `testImpl` **where i have my implementation class**:

The `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>testImpl</groupId>
<artifactId>testImpl</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Impl class looks like:

```
package implimentations;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import interfaces.Remotes.IClientRemote;
import interfaces.locals.IClientLocal;
@Stateless
public class Client implements IClientLocal, IClientRemote {    
private final static Logger LOGGER=LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);
public void showClientName() {
    LOGGER.info("The name of this client is ==> Alonso.");      
}
```

}

NB: when i add the anotation `@Override` above the `showClientName()` method it gives me that error : `The method showClientName() of type Client must override a superclass method` so when i remove it i works.

When i deploy the jar of `testImpl` project on the Jboss server EAP 6 it gives me these errors :

```
`16:21:31,395 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class implimentations.Client in Module "deployment.testImpl-0.0.1.jar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link implimentations/Client (Module "deployment.testImpl-0.0.1.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]`
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: interfaces/locals/IClientLocal
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: interfaces.locals.IClientLocal from [Module "deployment.testImpl-0.0.1.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
... 23 more`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS7 or EAP6 each deployed JAR and WAR file is treated as a module. In your case you have two separate deployments `test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `testImpl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, you need add the dependency from `testImpl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Dependencies can be configured adding entries to the `MANIFEST.MF` file of the deployment.

Eg:

```
Dependencies: deployment.test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

With maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>deployment.test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Alternatively  you can deploy all jar files in one ear file to resolve this problem.

See more:

- [Class Loading and Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html#Dynamic_Module_Naming1)
- [Add an Explicit Module Dependency to a Deployment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html)
- [Generate MANIFEST.MF entries using Maven](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Generate_MANIFESTMF_entries_using_Maven.html)